# Нужно проверить типы элементов массива с помощью метода every

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

Есть массив
`const a = [52, 'abc', 32, 15]` 
нужно создать функцию с методом 'every', которая выводит true, если найден элемент типа 'string'

Функция ниже, как оказалось, не работает

```
const arraySortInfo = (inputArray) => inputArray.every(function(elem) {
if (typeof elem == 'string') {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `.every()` вернёт `True` только если все элементы массива будут строками, и никак иначе. Вот справочный материал: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: Можно разобрать на примере: у тебя есть массив a = [52, "abc", 32], метод `every()` применит твою функцию к каждому элементу, но так как `True` вернут не все, `every()` вернёт `False`

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) проверяет что **все** элементы удовлетворяет условию.

Если нужно проверить что удовлетворяет **хотя бы один** лучше воспользоваться методом [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Однако, логическое выражение: существует хотя бы один удовлетворяющий условию - эквивалентно = не существует ни одного не удовлетворяющего.

Таким образом можно записать условие с помощью `every`

```
!arr.every((el)=> !condition(el))
```

Пример:

```js
const arraySortInfo = (inputArray) => !inputArray.every(function(elem) {
  return typeof elem != 'string'
})

const a = [52, 'abc', 32, 15]
const b = [52, 10, 32, 15]

console.log(arraySortInfo(a));
console.log(arraySortInfo(b));
```